# Performing different tasks according to the type of given data

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics, constraints

I am trying to create a game which has a weapon system where there will be weapon types such as Melee, Firearm and so on. I created classes for data, and then I will reference those data classes in another class and perform tasks (Fire, Reload and such) accordingly.

```
public abstract class WeaponData {
      public int damage;

      public abstract void Fire();
}
```

Note the abstract being, I am using this class as a base and for common stuff that every weapon will have. Then, we will have classes for each type of weapon that inherits this class above:

```
public class FirearmData : WeaponData {
     public SupplyData ammoTypeData;
     public int magazineSize;
     public AnimationClip reloadAnimation;

     public override void Fire() {
           // blablabla...
     }
}
```

This class overrides Fire() method and also has some other distinct fields. Here is another weapon type class:

```
public class MeleeWeaponData : WeaponData {
     public AnimationClip swingAnimation;

     public override void Fire() {
           // blablabla...
     }
}
```

So far, I managed to create these classes but it doesn't mean I won't create more classes like these two in the future, I left off it here because I figured out this system is not going to work...

So I have a Weapon class too, which I will reference a WeaponData and its methods will do different tasks according to the data.

```
public class Weapon {
     public WeaponData data;

     void Fire() {
         data.Fire();
     }

     void Reload() {
        // the problem is here;
     }
}
```

So the problem is here, I am including all the possible methods that the data would need in this very class, but this is not elegant if you ask me, because WeaponData would be MeleeWeaponData and in that case, it would not need a Reload() method, or an integer magazine field. I can still make it work, by doing some switch stuff to check the type of the data. But whenever I happen to create more data types, I would have to go here and add one more statement to the switch every time. And I don't want that.

So I wanted to consult to the Generics for this, like for example:

```
public class Weapon<T> where T : WeaponData {

}
```

But this wouldn't make me be able to get the fields of child classes of WeaponData either, as you told me...

Can you guys figure out a system that would work in my case? I am making my game on Unity and I do use ScriptableObjects for data stuff if that means anything.

Comment: Because you've constrained `T` to be an `X`, but `X` does not have a `field2`.

Comment: `field2` is field, it would require an instance... but this doesn't answer your real question.

Comment: Is there a way to access it? Without doing stuff like if (T is typeof(Y) something)?

Comment: @Masea `where T : Y`

Comment: @John: Yeah but I will have more classes that will inherit from X, I am using it for a base class. So I have to do it like where T : X

Comment: _Is there a way to access it_, only by checking the type at runtime, but that would strongly suggest a poor design.

Comment: @Masea That suggests to me a design problem then. If you edit your question to have more details about what you're trying to do perhaps we can suggest a better option, but at the moment this seems like an XY problem (you've tried to solve problem X by doing something, and this has led to problem Y, but that's not really the solution for X at all, so we're trying to fix the wrong problem).

Comment: Maybe if you showed your actual code, we may be able to suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: Alright guys, thank you, I will try to edit my OP and include more in-depth info about what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Guys, I edited my post, please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use interface instead:
IFireable, IReloadable, for example.

```
interface IWeapon
{
    void Fire();
}

interface IReloadable
{
    void Reload();
}
```

Implement your WeaponData ase

```
class WeaponData: IWeapon
{
    public int damage;
    public abstract Fire();
}
```

For firearm, derive from WeaponData, and implement IReloadable as well.

```
public class FirearmData : WeaponData, IReloadable
{
     public SupplyData ammoTypeData;
     public int magazineSize;
     public AnimationClip reloadAnimation;

     public override void Fire() 
     {
           // blablabla...
     }
     public void Reload() 
     {
           // Reload
     }
}
```

Fire MaleeData, derive from WeaponData only.

So that in your Weapon class, check the type of weapon, if it supports IReloadable, do the reload, otherwise, do nothing.

```
public class Weapon {
     public WeaponData data;

     void Fire() {
         data.Fire();
     }

     void Reload() {
        if(data is IReloadable reloadableData)
        {
             reloadableData.Reload();
        }
        else
            // Do nothing.
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you suggest anything else for the Reload() method within the Weapon class?

Comment: If the caller has direct access of weapon data, the caller only needs to check if the weapondata instance supports IReloadable.Reload, right? If you have the auto-reload logic, like, when the magazine is empty, perform the reload, then this logic can be added into the FirearmData.Fire(). If you need the gamer to manually reload, then the Reload Call has to be initiated by other part of the code.

Comment: So, Weapon class should also have an integer called magazine which carries the information of how many bullets loaded into the weapon. But given this field will not be necessary for an MeleeWeaponData, it going to stay there for nothing. What about this?

Comment: I guess you mean "bullets"? Bullets or ammunition is a concept of firearm, not to the generic concept of weapon, as there are knife or sword which does not need to replenish the ammunition and does not have "reload" concept. I think the problem here is that you are separating the data from action. (WIthin the Weapon class, you have WeaponData field, Fire method, Reload method) Better to get rid of weapondata from weapon class, or can we say, IWeapon interface?

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be something like this:

```
public abstract class WeaponData
{
    public int damage;

    public abstract void Fire();

    public virtual void Reload()
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Then override Reload() where needed:

```
public class FirearmData : WeaponData {
     public SupplyData ammoTypeData;
     public int magazineSize;
     public AnimationClip reloadAnimation;

     public override void Fire() {
           // blablabla...
     }

     public override void Reload() {
           // blablabla...
     }
}
```

And ignore it where it's not:

```
public class MeleeWeaponData : WeaponData {
     public AnimationClip swingAnimation;

     public override void Fire() {
           // blablabla...
     }
}
```

Comment: This way you are not using virtual as how it should be used.

Comment: @Masea Enlighten me.

Comment: Virtual methods should have an initial and common task. And if the child wants to do something different than that specific task, they should override it. But in your code, it has no initial task.

Comment: @Masea Sure it does, the initial task is to do *nothing*. Only special cases require more, as evident by the considerable number of added fields in `FirearmData`.